# CSV file: open in Python and print only links

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have CSV file with some links stored in one of the columns.  I want to read only links  and print them out. I tried to use following code but output is none.

```
import csv
filename ='abc.csv'
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
     for item in row:
         if item.startswith('http'):
             print(item)
```

Comment: Can you add some of the content from your `abc.csv` file?

Comment: @Das_Geek [' https://www.instagram.com/p/BSaxT9jlyKP/', ' Image may contain 2 people']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BSFthz6FgGg/', ' Image may contain 1 person']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BR-AefTlKIs/', ' Image may contain 4 people']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw6w7bfF7GR/', ' Image may contain 1 person standing and outdoor']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/Befnja0B2Cy/', ' Image may contain 1 person guitar']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BefePb0hhCZ/', ' Image may contain 3 people people standing']

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open ('abc.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        if line[0].startswith('http'):
            print(line)
```

## If you want to make sure that the line starts with for example "http" you should write:

## line[0].startswith("http")because the first element of the line list will be a string.

Comment: I tried to push following code. It is still not showing any out put. But when I try this code for row in data: for line in csv_reader: print(line) 
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BSaxT9jlyKP/', ' Image may contain 2 people']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BSFthz6FgGg/', ' Image may contain 1 person']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/BR-AefTlKIs/', ' Image may contain 4 people']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw6w7bfF7GR/', ' Image may contain 1 person standing and outdoor']
[' https://www.instagram.com/p/Befnja0B2Cy/', ' Image may contain 1 person guitar']

Comment: when i try  line[0].startswith("http")because the first element of the line list will be a string nothing is printed. I do n't understand what i am doing wrong!!

Comment: check the csv file itself, see if the problem lies within the file.